Was there a term in OT times to describe the relationship between two wives of the same man?
We read in 1 Sam 1: 1-1-2  ( KJV):

Now there was a certain man of Ramathaimzophim, of mount Ephraim, and his name was Elkanah, the son of Jeroham, ..............
And he had two wives; the name of the one was Hannah, and the name of the other Peninnah:

Modern languages have various words to express the relationship between two persons of a family circle, say cousins, sister-in-law etc . Polygamy being taboo to present day societies, one does not come across a word to describe the relationship  between two wives of the same man, as in the case of Hannah and Peninnah . But since polygamy was acceptable in OT times, was there a term  to express the relationship ? To specify : What was Hannah to  Peninnah ?

Check H6869 - ṣārâ - Strong's Hebrew Lexicon (kjv).
It lists "rival wife" as one of the meanings.

Short Answer: There is no specific term.

What we do know is that God's design for marriage established at creation is described as a monogamous relationship between “a man…and…his wife” (Genesis 2:24).
Polygamy was practiced in the Old Testament, however there is no specific term in the Old Testament to describe it. (Your example: the relationship between two wives of the same man).
What we know is that:

The record of these polygamous relationships is bristling with
discord, rivalry, heartache, and even rebellion, revealing the
negative motivations and/or disastrous consequences that invariably
accompanied such departures from God’s Edenic standard. [1]

Now, it's clear, as you stated, that modern languages have terms to describe all kinds of various familial relationships. However, a specific term for the relationship between co-wives in a marriage did not exist at the time (or at the very least has not been preserved). This is probably due to the cultural context of the time. Relationships were simply understood as a family structure, without the real need for a specific term.
The custom of having many wives was allowed under the Mosaic Law, which also applied to captives taken during foreign wars (Deuteronomy 21:1–17). Additionally, if he passed away without leaving any heirs, it provided for the continuation of the family line by marrying a brother's wife (Deuteronomy 25:5–12).
Take 2 Samuel 12:8 for example:

I gave you your master’s house and your master’s wives into your
keeping, and gave you the house of Israel and Judah. And if that had
been too little, I also would have given you much more!

נְשֵׁ֤י - nə-šê is used. Literally just a Noun - feminine plural construct.
The root word being:

ishshah: woman, wife, female
Original Word: אִשָּׁה
Part of Speech: Noun Feminine

To specify : What was Hannah to Peninnah?
Simply, Hannah and Peninnah were both wives of Elkanah. Perhaps we could call them "fellow wives"!

That is marvellous  ! ' Fellow wives'  by default are not designed to quarrel between themselves !

@KadalikattJosephSibichan Thank you. I appreciate the kind word!

Thanks. Stay blessed.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan If one can read between the lines, one knows that polygamy is not ideal. God made only one Eve for Adam. There is a reason why the first man that had two wives is described as a renegade (Lamech, Gen.4:19).

@KadalikattJosephSibichan Also, check my answer in that thread. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/75750/why-does-the-ylt-not-mention-sister-in-leviticus-1818/75757#75757

'Allowed' under Mosaic Law. But also exemplified in ten virgins, five of whom were foolish and, therefore, never consummated the marriage ; but five were gathered in (to one bridegroom). Thus spake Jesus of Nazareth.

The word for a co-wife is צָרָה (which appears in the Hannah-Peninnah story at 1 Samuel 1:6), from the root צרר, "to take a co-wife" (used in this sense at Leviticus 18:18, though usually meaning "to oppress").
